# archive as a page, so that it can be added in the wp_menu_nav

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

`http://localhost/lyrics/don't-turn-me-away/`
is a custom post type.

my question is how to display `http://localhost/lyrics/` as a page and not an archive?

my goal really is just for it be added to `wp_nav_menu`.

I have created a page named `lyrics` but it won't direct me there. Instead it brings me to `archive.php`. With that, the `lyrics` in menu, don't have the `current-menu-item` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for this in the code where you registered the lyrics post type:

```
'has_archive' => true,
```

Set `'has_archive' => false`.  That won't work right away, however.  So you need to go in an "refresh" your permalinks.  Just go to the permalinks options page, and hit the save button.

Comment: Also, you can add custom links to the menus in the menu editing screen.  Just copy the localhost/lyrics/ url and past it into the custom link box.

If you're going to be adding a lot of lyrics, you're better off creating a nice archive-lyrics.php and letting wordpress build the page for you.